# Are arrays separate from the java.util package?

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused about a technicality. I am completing a piece of work in Java, but there are restrictions on what we cannot use.

In particular, we not allowed to use the `Arrays` class from the `java.util` package.

I have used an array (`int[] example = new int[7]`), but as far as I understand, this is not included in the Arrays class - the Arrays class purely contains methods about dealing with arrays - such as `copyOf` and `binarySearch`.

Am I breaking the assignment rules?

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: as long as you're not using the "Arrays" class you're good to go. hence you're not breaking the assignment rules.

Comment: Assignment Rule - Make sure you avoid calling any method from [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class. Hope that would help.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not breaking the rules. Just don't use any Arrays api.
Yes the arrays are separate from Arrays class.
You can check this from a simple test
Create an array and check the result of '**instanceof**' test.
It will pass the test for Object class but fail for Arrays class
Arrays class in the java.util package is just for providing most commonly used operations like binary, sorting etc. It is just a utility class. You can observe in the documentation that it has no constructor and all the methods are **static**.
I hope this helps.